# Do max-width media queries mean "up to & including"?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a basic question about how media queries behave, specifically in the environment I'm using, which is Joomla 3.x and its default Protostar template.  I'll give a simple example and hopefully that'll illustrate where I'm having problems.

This is a test I ran based on a custom css file used with the template.  In this test, I want to have the font colors for the smallest displays in yellow, then up to orange, then red and then the default of black.

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    body.site {color: red;}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body.site {color: orange;}
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body.site {color: yellow;}
}
```

My expectation from reading a lot of different sources on media queries, both with and without using Protostar, would be this:

- From very low-res up to and including 480px the text would be yellow.
- From 481px up to and including 767px would be orange.
- From 768px up to and including 979px would be red.
- From 980px and higher would be the default of black.

However, the result I've seen from using Firefox's Responsive Design Mode tool is:

- From very low-res up to and including 480px the text is yellow, as I
  expected.
- From 481px up to and including 766px (not 767px) is orange.
- From 767px up to and including 978px (not 979px) is red.
- From 979px and higher is the default black.

So, my confusion is about how max-width really deals with ranges.  For example, I thought that "max-width" always means "up to and including" the specified viewport maximum size, but that hasn't always been the result.

Do I have a basic misconception of "max-width", or do I have it right but these unexpected (to me) results are related to the default break points defined in the template's css file...or maybe it's something else?